# вылетает приложение с сетевым запросом

Tags: android

если я делаю так, то приложение вылетает после нажатия на кнопку

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        get = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get);
        word = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.word);
        answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        userList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    getHttpResponse();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        userList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

Ошибка следующая:
*android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*
Как я понял это возникает из-за того, что сетевые запросы нужно делать в отдельном потоке. Только не пойму как разделить это.

Вот полный код ошибки:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7512)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1206)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22029)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22029)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22029)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22029)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22029)
    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:8550)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5419)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5275)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5232)
    at com.example.myapplication.Main2Activity$3.onResponse(Main2Activity.java:111)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коллбэк запроса в `OkHttp` вызывается в фоновом потоке, тогда как Андроид разрешает изменять UI только из UI-потока (о чём и говорит ошибка `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException`).
Сделать это можно с помощью класса `Handler`, методов `View.post(Runnable)` и `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)`

Пример вывода в `TextView`:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        textView.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            textView.setText("Failure !");
          }
        });
      }

      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) {
        String result;
        try { 
          result = response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
          result = "Error during get body";
        }
        textView.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            textView.setText(result);
          }
        });
      }
});
```

Comment: куда деньги высылать?)) именно этим и решилось

Comment: про разъяснение о потоках огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать данный код:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    }
});
```

Оберните им тот кусок кода на который указывает лог. Вот подобное [обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi).

Comment: Так у меня так и сделано public void getHttpResponse() throws IOException {

Comment: если закомментировать сетевой запрос, приложение падает?

Comment: пока не было записи в бд приложение работало, как только добавил бд так начало падать. БД работает отлично и без закоммичивания

Comment: значит поместите запись в бд внутрь блока, чтобы она происходила в другом потоке

Comment: я так понимаю так и сделано `@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // открываем подключение
        db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();`

Comment: поместите все действия с бд в такие блоки, чтобы выполнение происходило корректно, не только в одном месте может быть проблема

Comment: Судя по ошибке, не в бд проблема, а `onResponse` почему-то вызывается не в том потоке!? - странность какая-то конечно, но оборачивание как в ответе обращений к вью-элементам, ака `textView.setText(...)` в методе `onResponse`  может помочь. Хотя такого в принципе не должно быть - подозреваю, что либо клиент `OkHttp` неправильно настроен. Либо это глюк ускорителя отладки (не помню как он там сейчас называется) - теоретически должен помочь ребилд проекта, остановка процесса приложения и запуск по новой.

Comment: @woesss, разве проект не ребилдится при работе с эмулятором? по логике доступ из `onResponse` к элементам вью должен быть нормальным) если проблема в этом, то это не нормально :(

Comment: @Andrew, похоже мы привыкли к плюшкам Ретрофита, беглое гугление говорит, что в чистом OkHttp колбэк вызывается не в главном потоке.

Comment: @woesss, чаще всего решение приведенное в моем ответе мне помогает, я вот работаю с вебсокетами на чистом okhttp и это рабочий вариант должен быть :)

Comment: @Andrew, вообще-то работа с бд тоже "тяжёлая" и делать её в главном потоке не рекомендуется. `Room`, например, по дефолту без спец настройки, бросает исключение при запросах из главного. Тем более создание хелпера у автора и так в `onCreate` - там по-любому UI-thread

Comment: Обернул все что можно. Но проблема так и осталась. Рандомно вылетает ошибка, т.е. 5 раз все ок, а на шестой крашится. Запускаю не в эмуляторе

Comment: @woesss а на ретрофит у меня ума не хватило из-за такого разнообразия статей, вот нашел статью простую про okhttp и делал по ней

Comment: @Freedom, посмотрите в этой статье как работать с `OkHttp` на Андроиде: https://medium.com/@ssaurel/use-okhttp-to-make-network-requests-on-android-d3845e3c3f50 - если не получится, смотрите лог ошибки, куда она указывает и исправляйте там. Если ошибка изменилась - это уже другой вопрос. Если таки не получится исправить - публикуйте в вопрос код, на который указывает ошибка.